# fullCalendar updateEvent method not available

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, fullcalendar

i have [fullCalendar](http://fullcalendar.io/) working on a rails application. When a user clicks an event, an iframe with a form is open allowing the user to edit and update the contents of that particular event. This works fine, the problem is after the form is submited i want to rerender de event with the updated data.

So i set the event on update.js.erb:

```
event = { id: "<% @appointment.id %>",
      start: moment(new Date("<%= @appointment.start %>")),
      end: moment(new Date("<%= @appointment.end %>")),
      client_name: "<%= @appointment.client_name %>",
      status: "<%= @appointment.status %>",
      user_id: "<%= @appointment.user_id %>",
      provider: "<%= @appointment.user.name %>",
      title: title,
      allDay: false
};
```

And then call fullCalendar's [updateEvent](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/updateEvent/) method:

```
$('#calendar', window.parent.document).fullCalendar('updateEvent', event);
```

but updateEvent method appears as not available.

So i tried adding the method into appointments.js.coffee and call it like this:

```
window.parent.updateCalendar(event);
```

Then, on appointments.js.coffee:

```
@updateCalendar = (event) ->
  $("#calendar").fullCalendar "updateEvent", event
```

But this doesnt work neither. And i still find the method as < not available > on the browser's debugger. Even when $("#calendar").fullCalendar returns fullCalendar object just fine.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I can't help you too much as I'm not familiar with rails, but the FC method to call is `refetchEvents`, not `updateEvent`. http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/refetchEvents/ . (Provided that the changes have propagated to the DB)

Comment: thanks @slicedtoad, but refetchEvents refreshes all events. Isn't there a way to rerender only the updated event?

Comment: Eh, possibly, but FC isn't meant to be used like that. If you save something to the DB, you should refresh the events. It refreshes every time you change months anyway.